# How to get Instruction in MachineInstr?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llc

I wanted to know variable dependence in a real register (like X86:EAX, EBX ...). So, I have created an IR-PASS that can identify dependencies on the IR. This pass uses the newly added variables `unsigned HasDependency: 1;` and `unsigned HasMaybeDependency: 1;` in the `Value` class.

```
      .
      .
// Use the same type as the bitfield above so that MSVC will pack them.
unsigned IsUsedByMD : 1;
unsigned HasName : 1;
unsigned HasHungOffUses : 1;
unsigned HasDescriptor : 1;
unsigned HasDependency : 1;
unsigned HasMaybeDependency : 1;
      .
      .
      .
void setDependency() { HasDependency = true; }
void setMaybeDependency() { HasMaybeDependency = true; }
bool hasDependency() const { return HasDependency; }
bool hasMaybeDependency() const { return HasMaybeDependency; }

  //static_assert(sizeof(Value) == 2 * sizeof(void *) + 2 * sizeof(unsigned),
  //              "Value too big");
```

When applied to a code snippet like this:

```
extern int foo_called(int a);

int foo(int k)
{
    int __attribute__((annotate("xxx"))) a;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        int c = a + k;
        a += foo_called(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which produces this bitcode:

```
define i32 @"\01?foo@@YAHH@Z"(i32 %k) local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  %a = alloca i32, align 4
  %0 = bitcast i32* %a to i8*
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start.p0i8(i64 4, i8* nonnull %0) #2
  call void @llvm.var.annotation(i8* nonnull %0, i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8], [4 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0), i8* getelementptr inbounds ([6 x i8], [6 x i8]* @.str.1, i32 0, i32 0), i32 17)
  %cmp7 = icmp sgt i32 %k, 0
  br i1 %cmp7, label %for.body.lr.ph, label %for.cond.cleanup

for.body.lr.ph:                                   ; preds = %entry
  %.pre = load i32, i32* %a, align 4, !tbaa !3
  br label %for.body

for.cond.cleanup:                                 ; preds = %for.body, %entry
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end.p0i8(i64 4, i8* nonnull %0) #2
  ret i32 0

for.body:                                         ; preds = %for.body, %for.body.lr.ph
  %1 = phi i32 [ %.pre, %for.body.lr.ph ], [ %add2, %for.body ]
  %i.08 = phi i32 [ 0, %for.body.lr.ph ], [ %inc, %for.body ]
  %add = add nsw i32 %1, %k
  %call = call i32 @"\01?foo_called@@YAHH@Z"(i32 %add)
  %2 = load i32, i32* %a, align 4, !tbaa !3
  %add2 = add nsw i32 %2, %call
  store i32 %add2, i32* %a, align 4, !tbaa !3
  %inc = add nuw nsw i32 %i.08, 1
  %exitcond = icmp eq i32 %inc, %k
  br i1 %exitcond, label %for.cond.cleanup, label %for.body
}

declare i32 @"\01?foo_called@@YAHH@Z"(i32) local_unnamed_addr #3
```

The result of the the pass on the above bitcode is:

```
Function - ?foo@@YAHH@Z
    Annotated Variable List :
        - Annotated : a(message: xxx)

    Annotated-Variable : a
        (Perpect)  %add2 = add nsw i32 %2, %call
        (Perpect)  %2 = load i32, i32* %a, align 4, !tbaa !3
        (Perpect)  %a = alloca i32, align 4
        (Perpect)  %cmp7 = icmp sgt i32 %k, 0
        (Maybe)  %exitcond = icmp eq i32 %inc, %k
        (Maybe)  %inc = add nuw nsw i32 %i.08, 1
        (Maybe)  %i.08 = phi i32 [ 0, %for.body.lr.ph ], [ %inc, %for.body ]
        (Perpect)  %call = call i32 @"\01?foo_called@@YAHH@Z"(i32 %add)
        (Perpect)  %add = add nsw i32 %1, %k
        (Perpect)  %1 = phi i32 [ %.pre, %for.body.lr.ph ], [ %add2, %for.body ]
        (Perpect)  %.pre = load i32, i32* %a, align 4, !tbaa !3
```

I followed the `SelectionDAGISel.cpp: SelectAllBasicBlocks` function to get information from the backend, but I was able to get only `AllocaInst`, `StoreInst`, and `LoadInst` using as follows:

```
for (MachineBasicBlock &MBB : mf) {
  for (MachineInstr& I : MBB) {
    for (MachineInstr::mmo_iterator i = I.memoperands_begin(), 
      e = I.memoperands_end();
      i != e; ++i) {
      if (const Value *V = (*i)->getValue())
        errs() << *V << "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

How do I know the correlation between `MachineInstr` and `Instruction`? If it is not provided in LLVM, which parts need to be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not normal. This is an trick. But I am using this method very usefully. If you know the normal way, please give me a comment.

I solved this problem using `DebugLoc`. It is used to represent the line-column-row, function-name etc... information of `.c`, `.cpp` files. This information will remain from the time of `;;vm-ir` until `MachineInstr`.

So, if it is guaranteed that `DebugLoc` is not used in your compiler processing, you can put the address of the class that contains the information needed for the row information. This will allow you to cast the `DebugLoc` row to the desired class at the right time. (You can use column, because column must less than 2^16.)

The following describes in detail the method I used.

## Change file and Re-Build your project.

Several design patterns were used to maximize memory efficiency, so I could not easily change the class.

First, modify `DebugLoc-print` routine. GOTO `DebugLoc.cpp` and delete `DIScope` print routine like this. This processing save you form runtime-error.

```
void DebugLoc::print(raw_ostream &OS) const {
  if (!Loc)
    return;

  // Print source line info.
  //auto *Scope = cast<DIScope>(getScope());
  //OS << Scope->getFilename();
  OS << ':' << getLine();
  if (getCol() != 0)
    OS << ':' << getCol();
```

Second, The verifier should be modified. This syntax will be helpful.

```
void Verifier::visitDILocation(const DILocation &N) {
-  AssertDI(N.getRawScope() && isa<DILocalScope>(N.getRawScope()),
-           "location requires a valid scope", &N, N.getRawScope());
+  //AssertDI(N.getRawScope() && isa<DILocalScope>(N.getRawScope()),
+  //         "location requires a valid scope", &N, N.getRawScope());
   if (auto *IA = N.getRawInlinedAt())
     AssertDI(isa<DILocation>(IA), "inlined-at should be a location", &N, IA);
}
```

Third, there are some formal steps to register a class in `DebugLoc`. Create initialize function for this.

```
static LLVMContext cnt;
static MDNode *md;

md = MDNode::get(cnt, DILocation::get(cnt, 100, 100, DIScope::get(cnt, nullptr)));
```

Last, create register function.

```
static DebugLoc getDebugLoc(DependencyInstrInfoManager *info)
{
  return DebugLoc::get(reinterpret_cast<unsigned> (info), (uint16_t)-1, md);
}

static void setDebugLoc(Instruction *I, ...)
{
  DependencyInstrInfoManager *mgr;
  if (I->getDebugLoc()) {
    mgr = reinterpret_cast<DependencyInstrInfoManager *>
      (I->getDebugLoc()->getLine());
  } else {
    mgr = new DependencyInstrInfoManager();
    I->setDebugLoc(getDebugLoc(mgr));
  }
  mgr->addInfo(new DependencyInstrInfo(I, S, T, ...));
}
```

`DependencyInstrInfoManager` is the class for answering the above questions.

Finally, you can print your own information in `XXXMCInstLower.cpp:EmitInstruction();`(like X86MCInstLower.cpp). The following statement is an example of the output of my case.

```
void X86AsmPrinter::EmitInstruction(const MachineInstr *MI) {
  X86MCInstLower MCInstLowering(*MF, *this);
  const X86RegisterInfo *RI = MF->getSubtarget<X86Subtarget>().getRegisterInfo();

  if (MI->getDebugLoc()) {
    DependencyInstrInfoManager *mgr = reinterpret_cast<DependencyInstrInfoManager *>
      (MI->getDebugLoc()->getLine());
    mgr->doFolding();
    for (auto DI : *mgr)
      OutStreamer->AddComment(DI->getInfo());
  }
```

## Dependency Marking

I have done dependency marking using this method.

```
int foo(int k)
{
  int ANNORATE("b") b = 0;
  int ANNORATE("a") a = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
  {
    int c = a + k;
    int d = b + k;
    a += foo_called(c);
    b += foo_called2(c);
  }

  return a + foo_called(b);
}
```

to

```
# BB#1:                                 # %for.body.preheader
movl    %esi, %ebx
.p2align    4, 0x90
LBB0_2 : # %for.body
# =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  addl  %esi, %edi              # [Perpect, Source:b]
# [Perpect, Source: a]
  pushl %edi                    # [Maybe, Source:b]
# [Perpect, Source: a]
  calll "?foo_called@@YAHH@Z"   # [Maybe, Source:b]
# [Perpect, Source: a]
  addl  $4, %esp                # [Maybe, Source:b]
# [Perpect, Source: a]
  addl  %eax, 4(%esp)
  pushl %edi                    # [Perpect, Source:b]
  calll "?foo_called2@@YAHH@Z"  # [Perpect, Source:b]
  addl  $4, %esp                # [Perpect, Source:b]
  addl(%esp), %eax            # [Annotated, Source:b]
  movl  4(%esp), %edi           # [Perpect, Source:b]
# [Perpect, Source: a]
  decl  %ebx                    # [Maybe, Source:b]
  movl  %eax, (%esp)
  jne   LBB0_2
  jmp   LBB0_4
```